# Holoviews throwing XArrayInterface error with datashader and bokeh server

Tags: bokeh, holoviews, datashader

Upgraded to version 1.9.2 of Holoviews and now I'm getting the following error:

```
    DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format. XArrayInterface raised following error:

 cannot create a Dataset from a DataArray with the same name as one of its coordinates
```

The problem happens when trying to aggregate by a categorical field from a panda DataFrame.

```
       hover_opts = hv.opts("QuadMesh [tools=['hover']] (alpha=0 hover_alpha=0.2)")            
       self._points = hv.Points(df,kdims=[xFieldName,yFieldName])         
       self._dynamic_hover = datashade(self._points) * dynspread(datashade(self._points, aggregator=ds.count_cat(colorFieldName))) * \
         hv.util.Dynamic(aggregate(self._points, width=50, height=50, streams=[RangeXY]),operation=hv.QuadMesh)
```

If I remove the aggregator I loose the colors on my points but the plot works:

```
hover_opts = hv.opts("QuadMesh [tools=['hover']] (alpha=0 hover_alpha=0.2)")            
           self._points = hv.Points(df,kdims=[xFieldName,yFieldName])         
           self._dynamic_hover = datashade(self._points) * dynspread(datashade(self._points)) * \
             hv.util.Dynamic(aggregate(self._points, width=50, height=50, streams=[RangeXY]),operation=hv.QuadMesh)
```

I just need to give the points colors by this field.